# Getting attribute error: Series object has no attribute 'explode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to run python script which I am using explode(). In my local it is working fine but when I am trying to run on server it is giving error.

I am using below code:

```
df_main1 = (df_main1.set_index(['rule_id', 'applied_sql_function1', 'input_condition', 'input_value', 'and_or_not_oprtor', 'output_condition', 'priority_order']).apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.split(',').explode()).reset_index())
```

Error I am getting:

```
("'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'", u'occurred at index comb_fld_order')
```

Comment: what is pandas version in the server? looks like the server has a lower version of pandas than 0.25

Comment: The linked question is not an answer to this one. The correct answer is jezrael's and anky's: the version of pandas on the server is too old to use `explode()`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is different versions of pandas, because [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) working in later versions only:

> New in version 0.25.0.

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df_main1 = (df_main1.set_index(['rule_id', 'applied_sql_function1', 'input_condition', 'input_value', 'and_or_not_oprtor', 'output_condition', 'priority_order'])[col].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
```

Where `col` is the name of the string column, which you wish to split and explode.

Generally `expand` will do the horizontal `explode`, while `stack` will move everything into one column.

Comment: It is not working. It is not giving me the same result which explode was giving.

Comment: It adds extra indexes, right? Or something else? Could you elaborate on the input/output you want to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

I used to below code to get rid off from explode():

```
df_main1 = (df_main1.set_index(['rule_id', 'applied_sql_function1', 'input_condition', 'input_value', 'and_or_not_oprtor', 'output_condition', 'priority_order'])['comb_fld_order']
                    .astype(str)
                    .str.split(',', expand=True)
                    .stack()
                    .reset_index(level=-1, drop=True)
                    .reset_index(name='comb_fld_order'))
```

Comment: Cools - and it works, right? In such case - my suggestion would be to mark my post as an answer - cause it encapsulated the idea that solved your problem (SO isn't always about wrapping up the solution, it's meant to give a direction too)